# Should the loadURL webview method be on a separate thread

Tags: android-webview

Am using a webvew and wondering how the load url method should be handled.
Should this be called on a separate thread in case it takes time to connect or does it have to be on the UI thread?

Thanks
Ciaran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call all of the WebView methods on the UI thread, calling them on a different thread is not supported. The `loadUrl` method is asynchronous and won't block the thread.