# How to convert Document to String without exception?

Tags: java, android, webview, jsoup

I use **JavascriptInterface** and **JSOUP** to get **HTML** string from **URL** and load into **WebView** on click element inside webView, but problem is that after click app is crashing and throw in exception "Error Converting to String"
I tried many answears how to convert **Document** to **String** but nothing worked for me.
Please let me know what is wrong in my code...

```
WebView urlview = findViewById(R.id.urlview);
String newsUrlToShare;

Thread HtmlParser = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(newsUrlToShare).followRedirects(false).timeout(0).method(Connection.Method.GET).get();
                String body = doc.html();
                urlview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://google.com",body,"text/html","utf-8",null);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error Converting to String",ex);
            }
        }
};


private final class jsInterface{

        @JavascriptInterface
        public final void openNews(String url){

            urlview.post(() -> {
                if(!url.equals("")){

                    BrowserOpened = false;
                    newsUrlToShare = url;

                    HtmlParser.start();

                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information provided so that someone can help you.  Please Google how to ask a good question on SO.

Comment: What do you need to answer question?

Comment: What is the actual exception, `ex`? Add the full stack trace to the question. It probably comes from trying to access a view off the UI thread. Look up the `runOnUiThread` function. See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381437/should-the-loadurl-webview-method-be-on-a-separate-thread)